# Probability(A union B complement) given P(A) = .15, P(B) = .10, P(A intersect B) = .04

Tags: probability

This is a homework question that I'm stuck on and I'm looking to see if I'm going about it the right way and how to put the pieces together. So far I know that I can get $P(A \cup B)$ which is $0.15 + 0.10 - 0.04 = 0.21$ and I know that I can get $P(B^c)$ which is $1 - 0.10 = 0.90$, and I know I can get $P(A \cup B')$ by doing $1 - 0.21$ which is $0.79$. However I'm not sure what rule's I can use or how to use these individual parts to get $P(A \cup B^c)$????

Edited: This should have read $P(A \cup B)'$, what's needed is $P(A \cup B^c)$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Ok, thanks Alex. I now see how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P(A \cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A \cap B)$ (how?)

Once this is settled, rest follows easily.

$P(A \cup B^c)=P(A)+P(B^c)-P(A \cap B^C)$

$= P(A)+P(B^c) - P(A) + P(A \cap B)$

$ = P(B^c)+ P(A \cap B)$
$ = 0.90 + 0.04 = 0.94$

As you rightly note in the comments, there are multiple ways of reaching this result.

$P(A \cup B^c)=P(A)+P(B^c)-P(A \cap B^C) = P(A)+P(B^c \cap A^c) = P(A)+ 1 - P(B \cup A) $

because 
$P(B^c)-P(A \cap B^C) = P(A^c \cap B^c) $

Comment: Ahhh, ok. So then is it true that if you take the complement of P(A U B) which is .79 and add to P(A) which is .15 you get .94 the same way??? Or am I just making stuff up haha?

Comment: @jc707270 You are correct, check edit.

Comment: Cool, thank you axiom. I did it that way but thought I might have just been throwing stuff together.